# Make searched characters/words bold in results VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently creating a search box in VueJS.
Now my question is how to make letters that are searched bold in the results.

This is the part of code I have now:

```
<div v-for="result in searchResults.merk" :key="result.uid">
        <inertia-link :href="result.url">
            <strong v-if="result.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())">{{result.name}}</strong>
            <span v-else>{{result.name}}</span>
        </inertia-link>
    </div>
```

This sort of does what I want, but not really, now it makes the whole word bold if it contains these letters. I would like to only give those specific letters bold, and the rest of the word normal styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try splitting the word into a collection of in-line spans.

So you'd first iterate over the results. Then you'd iterate over each letter of the `result.name`, putting each individual letter in its own span.

Lastly, you'd toggle a bold class on the spam using the object class syntax.

Consider the following example:

```
<span 
    v-for="letter in result.name.toLowerCase()" 
    :key="letter" 
    :class={ isBold: searchInput.toLowerCase().includes(letter) }
>
{{letter}}
</span>
```

The object syntax for classes will toggle the class on or off if the condition to the right of the class name is true.

This isn't an ideal solution as it contains a reasonable amount of computational complexity (2x lowercase, and searching the search string for each letter). However, the use case is very simple so modern devices shouldn't struggle.

If you find it worth optimising, you can debounce the input and generate a map of the different letters lowercase search letters then search that map as map access is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Really don't understand how this can be an answer. If I search for "abc" I want only sequence "abc" to be highlighted, not every occurrence of characters "a", "b" and "c"...

Comment: Yeah you might be right. Your answer is honestly a very good one @MichalLevý but the OP accepted mine for a reason. Clearly they found it helpful, at least as a starting point perhaps. I was going off the fact he wrote "letters searched" which to me implied each individual letter

Answer (score 2):

See example below. It contains 2 solutions

1. Very simple but with the BIG warning as it is using [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML). `v-html` should not be used with user input for safety reasons (see the link). Luckily in this case if user enters some html into search box, it will be rendered only if it is also contained in searched text. So if searched text (`source` in example) is safe (produced by trusted source), it is perfectly save
2. Second solution is little bit involved - simply split the text into multiple segments, mark segments which should be highlighted and then render it using `v-for` and `v-if`. Advantage of this solution is you can also render Vue components (for example Chips) and use other Vue features (wanna bind a click handler on highlighted text?) which is not possible with `v-html` solution above...

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      source: 'foo bar baz baba',
      search: 'ba',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formatedHTML() {
      const regexp = new RegExp(this.search, "ig")
      const highlights = this.source.replace(regexp, '<strong>$&</strong>')
      return `<span>${highlights}</span>`
    },
    highlights() {
      const results = []
      if (this.search && this.search.length > 0) {
        const regexp = new RegExp(this.search, "ig")

        let start = 0
        for (let match of this.source.matchAll(regexp)) {          
          results.push({
            text: this.source.substring(start, match.index),
            match: false
          })
          start = match.index
          results.push({
            text: this.source.substr(start, this.search.length),
            match: true
          })
          start += this.search.length
        }
        
        if(start < this.source.length)
          results.push({ text: this.source.substring(start), match: false})
      }
      
      if (results.length === 0) {
        results.push({
          text: this.source,
          match: false
        })
      }

      return results
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="search" />

  <div>As HTML:
    <span v-html="formatedHTML"></span>
  </div>

  <div>Safe:
    <span>
      <template v-for="result in highlights">
        <template v-if="result.match"><strong>{{result.text}}</strong></template>
        <template v-else>{{result.text}}</template>
      </template>
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```